# how can i compress a video in android when upload it?

Tags: android, video, upload

My problem is that when i upload a video in android it take a long time to complete.

is there any way to compress the video before upload it? (don't zip it)

Comment: Use FFMPEG library for video size compress

Comment: hi, do you have some example ?    i lost the way

Comment: sorry, i hav'nt any idea yet.:(